# FormAuthentication Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, forms-authentication, basic-authentication

I have 2 pages : `Login.aspx` and `Default.aspx` in my root directory www. I am redirected from Login.aspx to Default.aspx if authentication is correct. Its working perfectly.

But if I write the url `http://localhost:4188/www/Default.aspx` on new tab of the  web browsers address bar, it directly showed the the `Default.aspx` without redirect to `Login.aspx`.

My web config file is as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms defaultUrl="default.aspx" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="20"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
<allow users="user"/>
<deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: confirm that you are not already logged in, place a loginview control on default.aspx page and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason may be you already logged in. try to reduce the timeout and check after sometime.

Or try `http://localhost:4188/www/Default.aspx` from another browser.

If one of above working correctly this is not a issue. Since you are already logged in even in new tab of the same browser you are redirected to default page. If you try to log off and access default page, then application will redirect you to login page.

Comment: In another browser it is redirected to login.aspx.  How can I enforce to expire it?

Comment: Go cookieless => embedding the authentication ticket in every url. That's the only way to separate two different windows/tabs (at least as long you don't use the same ticket in two different windows/tabs..)

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this problem if you desauthenticate the user logged in.You can put a button on your default.aspx called log off and program the onClick event like this:

```
 protected void logOffonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
```